# Add Namespace to the default WSSE Security Object in Suds

Tags: python, suds

I understand how to add a header to the SOAP request. But that generates a header that doesn't match the one I need to pass. That returns this header:

```
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <wsse:Security mustUnderstand="true">
         <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>CABLE</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>CABLE</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

However, I need to modify the namespace of that header to pass the particular namespace for the Security object and the UsernameToken object. I can't seem to figure out how to override the default values supplied.

```
<soapenv:Header>
 <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext">
       http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext
 <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility">
 <wsse:Username>CABLE</wsse:Username>
 <wsse:Password Type="wsse:PasswordText">CABLE</wsse:Password>
 </wsse:UsernameToken>
 </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Here is the Python Code to generate the above

```
security = Security()
token = UsernameToken('CABLE', 'CABLE')
security.tokens.append(token)
client.set_options(wsse=security)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. Here is the answer. Just need to use the ns argument

```
def createWSSecurityHeader(username,password):
    # Namespaces
    wsse = ('wsse', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext')

    # Create Security Element
    security = Element('Security', ns=wsse)

    # Create UsernameToken, Username/Pass Element
    usernametoken = Element('UsernameToken', ns=wsse)
    uname = Element('Username', ns=wsse).setText(username)
    passwd = Element('Password', ns=wsse).setText(password)

    # Add Username and Password elements to UsernameToken element
    usernametoken.insert(uname)
    usernametoken.insert(passwd)

    security.insert(usernametoken)
    return security
```

Comment: Thanks! It also solved my problem with suds wsse support and a missing type attribute on the password element (use passwd.set('Type', "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText") for instance to set the attribute.